# Python two string conditions: if x = "A" and "B" in y then do:

Tags: python

Is there a way to make Python use two conditions with at least one `in` statement when looking for string content?

Something like:

```
if (string1 == "Double" and "2x" in string2):
    leverage = "+200"
```

Comment: Yes, of coures. But your question is unclear. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'd like to do as the example. `If String1 == "Double and "2x" exists in string2`:

Comment: Did u try your code yourself and see if it's valid or not?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور No, I don't have access to an interpreter at the location I'm at right now.

Comment: @Winterflags what you have done works properly.

Comment: Ok...but you need to explain more what you want?...

Comment: try using online interpreter ideone.com

Comment: Braces unneeded I'd say, even for readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly is possible!  The code you have created is exactly how you would do it.

Explanation:

`string1 == "Double"` as well as `"2x" in string2` are both boolean comparisons.
Logical operators such as`and`, `or`, and `not` work regardless of comparison operators such as `in` and `==`.  So for all Python cares, you are comparing `True and False` or `False and False`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what logical operators `and` and `or` are for. They can combine any number of logical expressions together.

The original expression you wrote is viable.